# Mongodb and Mysql data types comparison

Tags: mysql, mongodb

I saw that some of data types in MySQL are not in MongoDB, is it so?

Please give me a comparison of the data types in MySQL and MongoDB.

Answer (score 5):

MySQL has a lot more data types than MongoDB, mainly because it supports more data types.

The first thing to understand is that all "data types" that are not the standard string or integer normally require wrappers, or rather objects encapsulation.

A good example here is the date, in MySQL you have `DATETIME`, `DATE`, `YEAR`, `TIMESTAMP` and so forth whereas MongoDB just has `ISODate()`.

No straight translation table actually exists however I will attempt to dig out the basic ones for you.

**Note**: for some unknown reason MongoDB Documentation has actually taken out the full list of data types available to you so I had to search around a little for this list hidden within the glossary: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/glossary/#term-bson-types

The first thing you will notice when looking at that list is that there are a lot of data types that do not exist in MySQL natively such as "Object" or "Array" however:

- `Binary` is sometimes called `BLOB` in MySQL and is normally accessed via `{d: new BinData($b)}`
- `ObjectId` is a special MongoDB data type used by MongoDB for primary key types
- `String` is `VARCHAR`, `TEXT`, `LONGTEXT` and all those other string types combined in MySQL and is normally used like `{d: 'lalalaalala'}`.
- `Boolean` is normally known as `BOOL` or `TINYINT(1)` in MySQL and it basically is used like: `{d:true}`.
- `Date` is known as `TIMESTAMP`, `DATE`, `DATETIME`, `YEAR` and all those other date types in MySQL and is used like `{d: new ISODate()}`
- 32-bit integer is sometimes known as `TINYINT(11)`, `INTEGER`, `INT`, `SMALLINT` etc  in MYSQL and other small integer data types and is used like `{d:5}`
- 64-bit integer is sometimes known as `MEDIUMINT` and `BIGINT` in MySQL and is used like `{d:new NumberLong("4")}`
- `NULL` is well `NULL` in MySQL and is used like `{d:null}`
- `Timestamp` is not one you will use publicly so I will not talk about that, it is not what it sounds like.
- `Double` relates to `DECIMAL` and `FLOAT` in MySQL and can be used like `{d:0.5}` however due to precision I recommend you store your floats and doubles as integers.

And I believe that covers the main ones you need to know about.

Quite a bit there so hope it helps.